# ValueError: could not convert string to float: after an input line

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've gone over the previous questions and answers regarding this error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I received this message after I coded a line of input asking for a radius. I made sure there were no punctuation marks in the line. I'm still not sure what the work around is. Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I have and the error message:

```
>>> str_r = input("Enter the Radius") 
Enter the Radius 
>>> r = float (str_r) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module> r = float (str_r) ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code and a quote of the error message.

Comment: The error indicate that the `input` return a string (or return something no compatible with `float`)

Comment: @LauraMKnight: Please add this to your question by editing it.

Comment: What exactly did you type at the command prompt?

Comment: if don't input a number, you will get this error

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I will tell you what happened.

You wrote:

```
var = input("enter a number please")
```

And then you assumed you could use it as a number, because it actually makes sense. But alas, it is a string.

So to fix this you need to cast:

```
var = float(input("enter a number please"))
```

Edit: If you actually used the code you commented then this error can't happen unless you `input`ted a string which isn't a number.